# Verify duplicate values on the array in Laravel5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to verify if email address in my database is duplicate or not?
Here is my codes :

```
'users.*.email'=> ['required','unique:users','email']
```

and this is my **Controller**

**UsersController**

```
public function MassStore(MassStoreUserRequest $request)
{

    $inputs = $request->get('users');
    return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
}
```

and this is my POST data (post data($inputs) will send like as below) :

```
'users' => [
    [
        'name' => 'Ken Tse',
        'email' => 'ken@gamil.com',
        'password' => 'ken12ken34ken',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Ken Tse',
        'email' => 'ken@gamil.com',   //duplicate, so need trigger error
        'password' => 'ken12ken34ken',
    ],
]
```

and this is error I get :

> [2019-12-10 15:51:16] local.DEBUG: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '`ken@gamil.com`' for key '`users_email_unique`'

MassStoreUserRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'users'                => ['required','array'],
        'users.*.name'         => ['required'],
        'users.*.email'        => ['required','unique:users','email'],
        'users.*.password'     => ['required','min:8']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the distinct with your email keyword such as :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'users'                => ['required','array'],
        'users.*.name'         => ['required'],
        'users.*.email'        => ['required','unique:users','email', 'distinct'],
        'users.*.password'     => ['required','min:8']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To prevent duplicate data being submitted in an array you can use the [distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-distinct) rule:

```
return [
    'users'            => ['required', 'array'],
    'users.*.name'     => ['required'],
    'users.*.email'    => ['required', 'email', 'distinct', 'unique:users'],
    'users.*.password' => ['required', 'min:8'],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use like this:

```
$rules = array(
            "name" => "required",
            "email" => "required|email|unique:users",
             "password" => "required|min:6",

        );
```