# Verify duplicate values (multi column unique) on the array in Laravel5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

relate as below issue

[Verify duplicate values on the array in Laravel5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261823/verify-duplicate-values-on-the-array-in-laravel5-7)

I am add two fields to data base.

```
// database/migrations/UpdateUsersTable.php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('staff_no' , 10);
        $table->string('staff_code');
        $table->unique(['staff_no', 'staff_code']);
    });
}
```

I want to verify if multi column unique in my database or post array value is duplicate or not?
Here is my codes :

this is my **Controller**

**UsersController**

```
public function MassStore(MassStoreUserRequest $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->get('users');

    //mass store process
    User::massStore($inputs);

    return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
}
```

and this is my POST data (post data($inputs) will send like as below) :

```
'users' => [
    [
        'name'       => 'Ken Tse',
        'email'      => 'ken@gamil.com',
        'password'   => 'ken12ken34ken',
        'staff_no'   => '20191201CT',
        'staff_code' => 'IT-1azz',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Tom Yeung',
        'email'      => 'tom@gamil.com',   
        'password'   => 'tom2222gt',
        'staff_no'   => '20191201CT', // staff_no + staff_code is duplicate, so need trigger error
        'staff_code' => 'IT-1azz',
    ],
]
```

MassStoreUserRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'users'                => ['required','array'],
        'users.*.name'         => ['required'],
        'users.*.email'        => ['required','unique:users','email', 'distinct'],
        'users.*.password'     => ['required','string','min:8'],
        'users.*.staff_no'     => ['required','size:10'],
        'users.*.staff_code'   => ['required','string']
        // how to set verify duplicate values(staff_no,staff_code unique) in here?
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  `'users.*.staff_code'   => ['required','string']` line to



'users.*.staff_code'   => ['required','string',  Rule::exists('staff')->where(function ($query) {
            //condition to check if staff_code and staff_no combination is unique
             return $query->where('staff_code', $request->('your_key')['staff_code'])->where('staff_no', $request->('your_key')['staff_no']) ? false : true; // You may need to make a loop if you can not specify key
        }),]
```

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean.

Could you post full coding ?

Comment: @シェバイクン as you can see, you have $query use that to write query to check if this combination already exists in db, return false. documentation has similar example check it https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation

Comment: my case are post by array,
first, how to get post array values on $query to setup it? And I not have Staff model. what is it?

next, In addition to the DB, the duplicate values(multi column unique) on the array needs to be checked.
As per your example, did not check for duplicate values(multi column unique) of array

Comment: @シェバイクン because of some network problem, my edits were not saved, check now, you will get better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-distinct) validation rule. So your code will look like-

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'users'                => ['required','array'],
        'users.*.name'         => ['required'],
        'users.*.email'        => ['required','unique:users','email', 'distinct'],
        'users.*.password'     => ['required','string','min:8'],
        'users.*.staff_no'     => ['required','size:10'],
        'users.*.staff_code'   => ['required','string', 'distinct']
    ];
}
```

Comment: hi, my database are setting to multi column unique

$table->unique(['staff_no', 'staff_code']);

'distinct' only check one field just like my question email.
so 'distinct' is not my want answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem myself.

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_validationData

main point is overrides method validationData(),make value "staff_no_code" to validation data.

Here is my codes :

MassStoreUserRequest

```
public function rules()
{
        $validate_func = function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $user = User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(staff_no,staff_code )", '=', $value))
                    ->first();
            if (!empty($user->id)) {
                $fail(trans('validation.alreadyExists')); 
            }
        };

    return [
        'users'                => ['required','array'],
        'users.*.name'         => ['required'],
        'users.*.email'        => ['required','unique:users','email', 'distinct'],
        'users.*.password'     => ['required','string','min:8'],
        'users.*.staff_no'     => ['required','size:10'],
        'users.*.staff_code'   => ['required','string']

        // 'distinct' check when working with arrays, the field under validation must not have any duplicate values.
        // $validate_func check DB exist
        'users.*.staff_no_code' => ['distinct',$validate_func]
    ];
}

    //make value "staff_no_code" to validation data
    protected function validationData()
    {
        $inputs = $this->input();
        $datas  = [];
        foreach ($inputs as $input ) {

             $input['staff_no_code'] = $input['staff_no'] .  $input['staff_code'];

             $datas[] = $input;
        }
        return $datas;
    }
```